# C# MySql Insert or Upadte Command Syntax for a Survey form with 78 Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax, command, insert-update

I have a C# Win form which contains (amongst other things) a popup panel with a survey containing 78 radio buttons. The survey has a submit button which inserts the data into a MySQL table. The code behind the click event should allow for updating as well as inserting (as people may fill the survey in several stages). The issue I am having is the MySQL INSERT command appears to have a syntax issue as when clicking submit the following exception is thrown...

[Error in SQL syntax near " at line 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxSFj.png)

My INSERT statement is currently

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO central_db.azt_image VALUES ('" + SerialCombo.Text + "', '" + Global.cust_dfe + "', '" + EngImgcomboBx.Text + "', '" + SerialCombo.Text + "', '" + AssetLocTxtBx.Text + "', '" + AssetNameTxtBx.Text + "', '" + (ImgL1Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL2Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL3Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL4Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL5Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL6Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL7Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL8Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL9Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL10Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL11Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL12Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL13Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL14Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL15Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL16Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL17Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL18Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL19Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL20Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL21Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL22Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL23Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL24Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL25Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL26Pend.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL1NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL2NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL3NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL4NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL5NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL6NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL7NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL8NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL9NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL10NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL11NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL12NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL13NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL14NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL15NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL16NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL17NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL18NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL19NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL20NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL21NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL22NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL23NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL24NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL25NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL26NA.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL1Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL2Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL3Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL4Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL5Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL6Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL7Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL8Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL9Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL10Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL11Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL12Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL13Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL14Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL15Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL16Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL17Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL18Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL19Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL20Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL21Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL22Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL23Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL24Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL25Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + (ImgL26Comp.Checked ? "1" : "0") + "', '" + ImgNoteTxt.Text + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;", conn);
```

As every INSERT or UPDATE always has a value for every column I have not declared the column headers. I am no MySQL expert (far from it) and I am not sure if the issue is the structure or syntax of the command... Any help would be greatly received as I have been struggling with this for a couple of days.

Comment: You should always use parameterized queries to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and to get rid of this kind of errors.

Comment: SQL Injection in this instance is not possible as all data is pre-inserted from another table based on a serial number chosen from a combo box (text boxes are read only). However parameterizing the statement may help with the error so I will give that a try... many thanks.

Comment: Can't you get the `cmd.CommandText` value being sent to the database so it is easier to find out what causes the syntax error?

Comment: Good call John... I dumped into a message box, the string looks OK though here's a snip: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtB8IvWSOXTujrMBv_EtUQ3lwcgVuQ) So really not sure what's throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the issue with my INSERT statement... When using the **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** option after the INSERT statement you must explicitly set the VALUES you wish to update i.e.

```
INSERT INTO some_database.some_table ( key, first_name, last_name, current_score) VALUES ("123", "John", "Doe", 69) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE current_score=69;
```

Once I had explicitly itemised the columns I wanted updating when a duplicate key is found the INSERT statement worked as it should...

Thanks for the comments, the StackOverflow community is just awesome...